# lebesgue measure is metric outer measure

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, lebesgue-measure

This question is driving me crazy.

I need to prove that Lebesgue measure is metric outer measure. Unfortunately, I get lost.

All I have is because $m$ is Lebesgue measure, $m^*(A \cup B) < m^*(A)+ m^*(B)$.

Then I think that since the distance between $A$ and $B$ is $> 0$, the cover for $A \cup B$ will cover the points between them. That will make it bigger than the cover for $A$ combined with the cover for $B$. Then they are equal.

But I still think it is not a good argument.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I also need to understand both of them in real life.. i mean what do they show exactly..

Comment: Can you stop all this editing for a while, @grantfgates, you're flooding the front page. Edit three or four old posts a day.

Comment: Oh sorry; I usually only look at "newest questions" and hadn't noticed.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you have that one (not strict!) inequality from sigma-subadditivity. Hence it is enough to prove the opposite inequality as well.

By definition of Lebesgue outer measure (and infimum in particular),
$$\forall \varepsilon >0 ,\, \exists (I_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}},\,  A \cup B \subset \cup_i I_i$$ and also
$$\sum_i \mathrm{Vol}(I_i) < m^{\ast}(A\cup B) + \varepsilon$$.

You can subdivide each interval $I_i$ into smaller ones, such that for the new intervals, it holds that $\mathrm{diam}(I_i) < \mathrm{dist}(A,B)$, thus  every interval $I_i$ intersects atmost one of the sets $A,\,B$.

Then you can consider two subfamilies $(I^{'}_i),\, (I^{''}_i)$ intersecting only $A,\, B$ respectively, and therefore you have:

$$m^{\ast}(A)+m^{\ast}(B) \leq \sum_i \mathrm{Vol}(I^{'}_i) + \sum_i \mathrm{Vol}(I^{''}_i) \leq \sum_i \mathrm{Vol}(I_i) < m^{\ast}(A \cup B) + \varepsilon$$.

Which proves the other inequality.